# PhpED debugging not working after upgrading to Version 12

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, phped

I'm a long time user of PhpED and just upgraded from V10 to V12. After upgrading the software and the debugger, debugging no longer works on a remote Linux server. Debugging locally using XAMPP works.

I've been using the SSH tunnel option to debug remotely up to V10 with no problems. As an experiment, I unchecked the "Use SSH tunnel" option in debugger settings. After I did that, I can debug a single page using the Internet Explorer toolbar (IE11), however setting the "Debug session" option no longer works. Also, the DBGbar with Firefox no longer works at all.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on what could be wrong.

Comment: I have also been unable to get debugging to work with v12.

Comment: I'm also a long time user of PhpED and sometime in the last several weeks debugging in Firefox stopped working. However it does work in IE 11 and locally using Xampp. I also tried the debugger add-on for Chrome and that does not work.    I get the error: Failed to start DBG session

Reason: failed to connect to the client at 127.0.0.1:7869, please make sure that IDE is running

Comment: Switched to PHPStorm...

Comment: I had a similar problem, i.e. the debugger stopped working with DBGbar for Firefox. In the DBGbar options, I had Machine clienthost set to "localhost". After changing it to "clienthost", the Firefox debugger toolbar started working again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't debug PHP Cli after Eclipse update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352975/cant-debug-php-cli-after-eclipse-update)