# PhpED debugging not working after upgrading to Version 20

Tags: debugging, phped

I'm a long time user of PhpED and just upgraded from V19.5 to V20.

Of course, I paid for that.

Since then I have a problem with the debugger connectivity through SSH tunnel, which is that it no longer connect at all.

On all relevant projects.

From all of my nine remote servers at once.

Then suspecting an issue with my main computer, I took another computer which still had an older PhpED version installed (19.1 if I remember well).
It worked properly with my remote servers that still have a PHP version compatible with it.

Then I upgraded on this other computer with the intermediary version 19.5.
It still worked, with more PHP versions.

Then I upgraded, still on this other computer, with my last PhpED version, 20.0, same as my main computer. No configuration change.
And there also, the remote debugger module stopped connecting with the computer, likely on all servers (I didn't want to spend more time testing all of them).

Of course, I switched the remote debugger module version each time.

Reaching that point, I asked for technical support on the NuSphere site (who own that software).

It took a long time before I get an answer, which was this one:

> I'm sorry for delay.
>
> What you have is PhpED Personal license, it comes with no technical support.
>
> I understand that you may think there is an issue in our product because previous version worked.
>
> If that's the case, I can assure you -- there is no such problem on our side. Protocols evolve, > > security and safety related features are constantly revisited and improved according to the latest > protocol requirements.
>
> You may want to revisit your server settings or relax configuration settings that v20 comes with by default. But I highly recommend you not to relax because all weak ciphers and hmacs are disabled by default on purpose to make communications
> safer and protect from potential attacks.
>
> I'm sorry if it sounds rude, but I have no choice -- you need to update to Pro license if you want me to dig into the problem details. It's definitely your choice. The upgrade to PRO is available for the price difference on the following page
> https://shop.nusphere.com/customer/home.php?cat=15

Let's me insist on the fact that this problem is the only effect of applying an upgrade with no intervening change.

Technical support is help for users *having specific issues not concerning other users*.

Fixing bugs and even clarifying documentation is the minimal help that developers owe to all their end users, whatever they subscribed to technical support or not.

To me, buying an upgrade for a working product and having this product drily no longer working on an essential feature after having made only this upgrade is something which should never happen.

Thus I think that there, I was not really asking for technical support.

I was asking for minimal warranty.

One can sell a product without support, but this implies that the product have to be sold with enough documentation for allowing end users to use it without support in all common cases without having to ask anybody, or at least, very commonly, by asking into a space where end users could talk among them for sharing experiences, and also nevertheless collectively get official support for major critical issues.

If protocols has evolved between 19.5 and 20.0 in such a way that it could make connectivity not straightly working or hardly working, this should be clearly documented, and all necessary instructions for allowing end users to solve this by themselves should have been provided with the upgrade without deeply digging.

Here, I realise that I bought an upgrade that I will be unable to use, and then all that their support found to answer, is that if I want it to work, I have to pay more in order to have them fixing the problem.

To me, this is not less than “forced sale”.

What would you do in such case?

Please note that this seems to not be the first issue of this kind from Nusphere PhpED.
I've also found this thread here on a similar subject:
[PhpED debugging not working after upgrading to Version 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764972/phped-debugging-not-working-after-upgrading-to-version-12)

But that user didn't seem to have asked their technical support. Maybe he should have.